# Node Express & JSON Response Format

Tags: json, node.js, express

I am wondering why I am getting my JSON response with escaped double quotes. What is the best practice for sending JSON response back to client?

**The code**

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
var country = '';
var dataStr = '[{"country_code" : "USA", "country_name" : "United States","bac_limit" : 0.80}, { "country_code" : "CAN", "country_name" : "United States","bac_limit":0.80}]';
connectToMongoDb();

server.get('/', function(req, res){
   country = req.query.country;
   res.json(dataStr);
});
server.listen(8080);
```

**The Output**

```
"[{\"country_code\" : \"USA\", \"country_name\" : \"United States\",\"bac_limit\" : 0.80}, { \"country_code\" : \"CAN\", \"country_name\" : \"United States\",\"bac_limit\":0.80}]"
```

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify('[{"country_code" : "USA"}]')` - as long as you are trying to stringify a string the result is what you get. The best response it just stringified array

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski you stringify a string that already contains data encoded as JSON.

Comment: @t.niese As same as `dataStr` covers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dataStr` is actually a string, and `res.json` call is sending the string as such. If you wish to send the data as JSON, don't put it as a string, but a JS object/array (or use `JSON.parse`):

```
var dataStr = [{"country_code" : "USA", "country_name" : "United States","bac_limit" : 0.80}, { "country_code" : "CAN", "country_name" : "United States","bac_limit":0.80}]
// alternatively, JSON.parse(dataStr)
connectToMongoDb()

server.get('/', function(req, res){
 country = req.query.country
 res.json(dataStr)
})
```